# how can i call a function inside ember octane template without event?

Tags: javascript, function, loops, math, ember.js

I have a function called calculatePercentage which take a value and return percentage  if i want to call this function inside every li such as

```
<li>{{this.calculatePercentage 1023 0 5000}}</li>
```

without any user event how can i do that in ember octane app  ?

```
export const calPrecOfTwoNums = (num: number, min: number, max: number) => {
    let precentageResult = Math.round((((num - min) * 100) / (max - min)));
    if(precentageResult < 0) {
        precentageResult = 0;
    } else if(precentageResult > 100) {
        precentageResult = 100;
    }
    return precentageResult;
}
```

Comment: you could also make it a native getter. native es5 getters are like functions, but you access them with properties -- only downside is that they don't take args, so you'd need to abstract away the args

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to [write a helper](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/templates/writing-helpers/).

Generate the helper through ember-cli:

`ember generate helper calculate-percentage`

This will generate a file for your helper in the correct location. In there, place your function, but modify the parameters a bit:

```
export default function calculatePercentage([num, min, max]) {
    let precentageResult = Math.round((((num - min) * 100) / (max - min)));
    if(precentageResult < 0) {
        precentageResult = 0;
    } else if(precentageResult > 100) {
        precentageResult = 100;
    }
    return precentageResult;
}
```

Then you can use it in a template like so:

```
<li>{{calculate-percentage 1023 0 5000}}</li>
```